# Unit test request-promise, promise() is not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, request-promise

I am trying to unit test this function with sinon/mocha which uses `request-promise`. I attach the `.promise()` to allow access to all the Bluebird promise methods.

According to the `request-promise` readme:

```
rp(...).promise() or e.g. rp.head(...).promise() which returns the underlying promise so you can access the full Bluebird API
```

**myModule.js**
    var requestPromise = require('request-promise');

```
function requestWrapper(opts) {
   // Adds .promise() to allow access to Bluebird methods
   return requestPromise(opts).promise();
}

module.exports = requestWrapper;
```

**Unit test**

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var requestPromise = sinon.stub().returns(Promise.resolve());
var rewire = require('rewire');
var myModule = rewire('./myModule');

myModule.__set__({
  requestPromise: requestPromise
});

describe('myModule', function() {
  var testPromise;

  it('should...', function() {
      testPromise = myModule.requestWrapper({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://someurl.com' })
  });
});
```

**Error**

I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: requestPromise(...).promise is not a function`.

Answer (score 1):

You're mocking is wrong (but close).

`request-promise` is a function that returns an object that has a function `promise` that returns the underlying promise.

What you've done with your stub & rewire is set `request-promise` to be a function that returns a promise.

---

A possible fix:

```
var requestPromise = sinon.stub().returns({ promise: () => Promise.resolve() });
```